# Reading first 3 sentences of a text file and displaying on the screen

Tags: android, text, split

I am trying to read first 3 sentences of a text file and display it as a TextView. My intention is to split each sentence after a full stop and send each sentence to an array list. Then display first three sentences stored in the array list. This is the code that I have to loop through text and obtain first 3 lines.

```
         reader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("inputNews.txt")));
         String line;        
         List<String> sentence = new ArrayList<String>();
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sentence.add(line.split("[\\.\\?\\!][\\r\\n\\t ]+")[0] + ".");
                if(sentence.size() < 4){
                    text.append(sentence);
                    text.append('\n');
                }
```

Then I output this information using,

```
    TextView output= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.summtext);
    output.setText((CharSequence) text);
```

However, when I run this program, it reads through the file and prints out text like this,

```
   [Sentence one..]
   [Sentence one..Sentence two.]
   [Sentence one..Sentence two. Sentence Three..]
```

I don't know why it is producing double full stops(..) and []. My intention is to obtain a result like this,

```
  Sentence one. Sentence two. Sentence three.
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are appending the full list to the text for each sentence.

Change this line:

```
text.append(sentence);
```

to this:

```
text.append(sentence.get(sentence.size()-1));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks it worked. There should be an extra ")" in the code right at the end.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the *+"."* from *sentence.add* to remove the extra added period (your code found one in the text and you are adding the second one here).   The brackets won't be removed by this.

Comment: Why should that fix the problem?

Comment: thanks, it stopped the additional full stop but the main issue is still there

Comment: Thanks Nanoc.  Edited.